# Executing concurrent example in Erlang code from command line

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

I'm testing the code in [Getting Started with Erlang User's Guide](http://www.erlang.org/doc/getting_started/conc_prog.html#id67906) Concurrent Programming Section.

In `tut17.erl`, I started a process with `erl -sname ping`, and another process with `al -sname pong` as the guide described.

```
-module(tut17).
-export([start_ping/1, start_pong/0, ping/2, pong/0]).

ping(0, Pong_Node) ->
    {pong, Pong_Node} ! finished, 
    io:format("ping finished~n", []);

ping(N, Pong_Node) ->
    {pong, Pong_Node} ! {ping, self()}, 
    receive
        pong ->
            io:format("Ping received pong~n", [])
    end,        
    ping(N - 1, Pong_Node).

pong() ->
    receive
        finished -> io:format("Pong finished~n", []);
        {ping, Ping_PID} -> 
            io:format("Pong received ping~n", []), 
            Ping_PID ! pong,
            pong() 
    end.

start_pong() ->
    register(pong, spawn(tut17, pong, [])).

start_ping(Pong_Node) ->
    spawn(tut17, ping, [3, Pong_Node]).
```

From the ping and pong process, I could invoke the start_ping and start_pong to check everything works fine.

```
(ping@smcho)1> tut17:start_ping(pong@smcho).
<0.40.0>
Ping received pong
Ping received pong
Ping received pong
ping finished  

(pong@smcho)2> tut17:start_pong().
true
Pong received ping
Pong received ping
Pong received ping
Pong finished
```

I'm trying to run the same code from a command line; For a simple hello world example:

```
-module(helloworld).
-export([start/0]).

start() ->
    io:fwrite("Hello, world!\n").
```

I use the following command line:

```
erlc helloworld.erl
erl -noshell -s helloworld start -s init stop
```

So, I just tried with the following, but ended up with a crash.

- From ping node: `erl -noshell -sname ping -s tut17 start_ping pong@smcho -s init stop`
- From pong node: `erl -noshell -sname pong -s tut17 start_pong -s init stop`

However, I got this error report from the `ping` when `pong` ends without printing anything.

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 6-Mar-2015::20:29:24 ===
Error in process <0.35.0> on node 'ping@smcho' with exit value: 
    {badarg,[{tut17,ping,2,[{file,"tut17.erl"},{line,9}]}]}
```

Compared to the REPL approach, with command line, each process does not wait for the counterpart to response, but stops after some time. 
What might be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arguments from the command line are received as a list of atoms when using the `-s` switch, and a list of strings when using the `-run` switch. With this in mind, let's think through what happens...

This command is issued from the shell:

```
erl -noshell -sname ping \
    -s tut17 start_ping pong@smcho \
    -s init stop
```

So `start_ping/1` is being called with the argument `[pong@smcho]`. It is then calling `ping/2` as `ping(3, [pong@smcho])`, which in its first line tries to do `{pong, [pong@smcho]} ! {ping, self()}`. Because a list is not a valid target for a message... your world explodes.

To run this both from the Erlang shell and the system shell comfortably you could add a clause to `start_ping/1`:

```
start_ping([Pong_Node]) ->
    spawn(tut17, ping, [3, Pong_Node]);
start_ping(Pong_Node) ->
    start_ping([Pong_Node]).
```

Answer (score 2):

There are some changes needed.

#### start_ping

From `zxq9`'s hint, I modified the start_ping function.

```
start_ping([Pong_Node]) ->
    io:format("Ping started~n", []),
    spawn(tut17, ping, [3, Pong_Node]);
start_ping(Pong_Node) ->
    start_ping([Pong_Node]).
```

#### Invoke the `init:stop()` when process is finished.

I'm not sure this is absolutely necessary, but it seems to be working with this modification.

```
ping(0, Pong_Node) ->
    {pong, Pong_Node} ! finished, 
    io:format("ping finished~n", []),
    init:stop();
```

Then I could remove `-s init stop` from the shell command: `erl -noshell -sname ping -s tut17 start_ping pong@smcho`.

#### Execution order

Pong should be invoked before Ping is invoked.

#### The updated code

This is the revised code:

```
-module(tut17).
-export([start_ping/1, start_pong/0, ping/2, pong/0]).

ping(0, Pong_Node) ->
    {pong, Pong_Node} ! finished, 
    io:format("ping finished~n", []),
    init:stop();
ping(N, Pong_Node) ->
    {pong, Pong_Node} ! {ping, self()}, 
    receive
        pong ->
            io:format("Ping received pong~n", [])
    end,        
    ping(N - 1, Pong_Node).

pong() ->
    receive
        finished -> 
            io:format("Pong finished~n", []),
            init:stop();
        {ping, Ping_PID} -> 
            io:format("Pong received ping~n", []), 
            Ping_PID ! pong,
            pong() 
    end.

start_pong() ->
    io:format("Pong started~n", []),
    register(pong, spawn(tut17, pong, [])).

start_ping([Pong_Node]) ->
    io:format("Ping started~n", []),
    spawn(tut17, ping, [3, Pong_Node]);
start_ping(Pong_Node) ->
    start_ping([Pong_Node]).
```

#### The shell commands:

- ping: `erl -noshell -sname ping -s tut17 start_ping pong@smcho`
- pong: `erl -noshell -sname pong -s tut17 start_pong`

Comment: Nicely done. Using `init:stop/0,1` for this is very convenient. Before you make it a habit keep in mind that it does shut down the entire node (which is exactly what you want here), so it can be the wrong answer for an OTP application or almost *any* code that might run alongside other code within the same node.